# Nginx, rewrite url for one subdomain with condition, without new virtual host

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to rewrite a URL for only one specific subdomain. The logical solution seemed to be using if-else to check whether the current subdomain was that one.

I don't want a new virtual host, because I have a lot of things set to subdomains in general and it would be chaotic if I made a long section for every subdomain.

With Apache, it was easy, just an .htaccess file where I want and done. Is there a way in nginx that works as good as this?

What I tried was something like this:

```
if ($subdomain = 'foo') {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}
```

Doesn't work. Any idea how?

P.S.: Just to clarify: the variable `$subdomain` contains the name of the subdomain. And they look like: subdomain.martinfejes.hu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bad approach - because nginx works with virtual hosts in very-very fast manner, opposite to working with conditions. Generally spealing, conditions are interpreted by "simple virtual stack machine" (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals) and are slow.

Also, using virtual-host will limit possible side effects, as now as in future configuration complexity.

Comment: Although it is not exactly the answer I was looking for, this is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex matching like this:

```
server {
    server_name ~ ^foo\.;

    location / {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }
}
```